# S3 Actions from ActiveMQ (IoT Core)

Tags: mqtt, aws, esp32

I am working on a code for ESP32 which needs to transfers data that is sent via MQTT to AWS S3 storage.

Can Someone help me out on how I can achieve this ?

I have setup the the client and AWS broker as well. I need help to transfer messages to S3 by adding rules.

Answer (score 2):

One way is you have to create the web service which upload the data on S3. 
and call service through http protocol.
1. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_services.asp use this to create the webservice or use angular 2 for creating the rest service call
https://sniederm.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/tutorial-ng2-rest-service/

Comment: AWS Iot core has something called rules to directly send the mqtt messages to S3. Do you know how to use that ?

Comment: which broker you are using tell me some more about the MQTT details

Comment: I am directly using the AWS Broker that's in AWS